# How do I fix these errors?

Tags: 7, javascript

I've been currently developing a module, which was working fine. Now, the console throws an error every time I click a link in the administrator menu.

> [image: screenshot]

For example, when I click the *Content* link, I get this error.

> [image: screenshot]

When I click the *Dashboard* link, I get this error.

> [image: screenshot]

I added the jquery-1.11.2.min.js file with `hook_init()` to make the module work.

```
function myid_init () {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path("module", "myid") . "/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js");
}
```

How can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would wager a guess it's because (or related to) Drupal including it's own version (1.4) of jquery, and you trying to include a second copy at version 1.11.2 - some functionality is deprecated in later versions of jquery, items that drupal and its modules are expecting to find. If you need to increase the version use something like the module [Jquery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) instead of your own add_js and see if that solves it.

> Upgrades the version of jQuery in Drupal core to a newer version of
> jQuery.
>
> Updates...
>
> Drupal 5 to jQuery 1.2.6
>
> Drupal 6 to jQuery 1.3.2
>
> Drupal 7 to jQuery 1.5.x, 1.7.x, 1.8.x, 1.9.x, 1.10.x and jQuery UI 1.10.2
>
> Drupal 8: TBD